# A type is listed in GetCurrentRegistrations, but Verify fails saying type not registered

Tags: c#, simple-injector

I'm using SimpleInjector v3.2.7. The failure happens when trying to construct a Web Api `HeartbeatController`. Its constructor looks like this:

```
public HeartbeatController(IHeartbeatService heartbeatService, IMainDbVitalCheck mainDbVitalCheck, ICacheVitalCheck cacheVitalCheck)
```

When calling `container.GetCurrentRegistrations()` (before `container.Verify()`), I see a registration for `IHeartbeatService` that is mapped to `HeartbeatService` - this is the mapping I want.

But the call to `Verify()` fails with the following error:

> The configuration is invalid. Creating the instance for type
>   IHttpController failed. The constructor of type HeartbeatController
>   contains the parameter with name 'heartbeatService' and type
>   IHeartbeatService that is not registered. Please ensure
>   IHeartbeatService is registered, or change the constructor of
>   HeartbeatController.

Here is my container setup:

Global.asax.cs

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    SimpleInjectorWebCommon.SetUpWebApi(config);
    // ...
    // Other unrelated stuff
    // ...
}
```

SimpleInjectorWebCommon.cs

```
public static Container DiContainer { get; private set; }

public static void SetUpWebApi(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    InitContainer(config);
    config.DependencyResolver = new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(DiContainer);
}

public static void InitContainer(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var container = new Container();
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebApiRequestLifestyle();
    container.Options.ConstructorResolutionBehavior = new GreediestConstructorBehavior();
    container.Options.AllowOverridingRegistrations = true;

    RegisterServices(container);
    container.RegisterWebApiControllers(config);

    container.Verify();

    DiContainer = container;
}

private static void RegisterServices(Container c)
{
    // ... other registrations
    RegisterSingleImplementations(c);
    // ... other registrations
}

// My gut tells me the problem is somewhere in here
private static void RegisterSingleImplementations(Container c)
{
    var assemblies = GetAllBinAssemblies("DSI.*.dll").ToList();
    foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
    {
        var registrations = assembly.GetExportedTypes()
            .Where(t => !t.IsAbstract)
            .Where(t => t.Namespace != null && t.Namespace.StartsWith("DSI."))
            .Where(t => GetDirectInterface(t.GetInterfaces()) != null)
            .Select(t => new { Service = GetDirectInterface(t.GetInterfaces()), Implementation = t});


        foreach (var reg in registrations)
        {
            try
            {
                c.Register(reg.Service, reg.Implementation, Lifestyle.Scoped);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

**Update**

The problem was in how I was loading assemblies during scanning to get a list of types to register. I used `Assembly.Load` which would eventually cause the assembly to appear twice in the current `AppDomain`. I since switched to using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load` and now the assembly only appears once in the app domain. Here is the implementation of assembly scanning:

```
    private static IEnumerable <Assembly> GetAllBinAssemblies(string searchPattern)
    {
        var assemblyPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
        var privateBinPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.PrivateBinPath;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(privateBinPath))
        {
            return GetAssemblies(assemblyPath, searchPattern);
        }
        if (Path.IsPathRooted(privateBinPath))
        {
            return GetAssemblies(privateBinPath, searchPattern);
        }
        return
            privateBinPath.Split(';').SelectMany(bin => GetAssemblies(Path.Combine(assemblyPath, bin), searchPattern));
    }

    private static List <Assembly> GetAssemblies(string path, string searchPattern)
    {
        return Directory
            .GetFiles(path, searchPattern)
            .Select(f => AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(f)))
            .ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say, but Simple Injector is typically not wrong ;-) so you can rest assure that the `IHeartbeatService` interface that `HeartbeatController` depends upon is *not registered*.

There are typically two reasons what can go wrong here:

1. You accidentally defined a second interface in the code base with the same name, while you registered the other.
2. The same assembly is loaded twice in the AppDomain under a different identity (for instance when the same assembly gets loaded from two locations), which causes there to be 2 interfaces at runtime.

To check whether the registered `IHeartbeatService` is the same type as the `HeartbeatController`'s constructor argument, run the following code just before calling `container.Verify()` and after `RegisterWebApiControllers`:

```
var heartbeatServiceRegistration = (
    from r in container.GetCurrentRegistrations()
    where r.ServiceType.Name == "IHeartbeatService"
    select r)
    .Single();

var parameterType =
    typeof(HeartbeatController).GetConstructors().Single()
    .GetParameters().First().ParameterType;

bool areSame = 
    object.ReferenceEquals(parameterType, heartbeatServiceRegistration.ServiceType);

if (!areSame) throw new Exception("different types");

container.Verify();
```

If `areSame` is false, it means that there in fact are multiple interfaces named `IHeartbeatService` for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but after looking at the loaded assemblies list and verifying the type name, it doesn't look like the assembly is loaded twice, and there is only 1 interface defined with that name. Is there a chance that this could be caused by an incorrect use of one of the `.Register...` methods? Could this be related to the `WebApiRequestLifecycle`? Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @DanielGabriel Please call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` after the call to `RegisterSingleImplementations` and check if the returned list contains multiple assemblies with an identical name.

Comment: "Is there a chance that this could be caused by an incorrect use of one of the .Register... methods? Could this be related to the WebApiRequestLifecycle?" Nope. There is no way to use `Register` incorrectly.

Comment: @DanielGabriel: Please see my update. I posted some code that allows you to verify whether there are multiple interfaces at runtime with the same name.

Comment: After following your suggestions I found out the following: 1. The types are NOT the same 2. There are 2 versions of the same assembly in the AppDomain. I assume this is caused by my calling `Assembly.LoadFile` in the `GetAssemblies()` method. Can you recommend a better way to scan all assemblies in a directory and batch-register them all to the first directly inherited interface?

Comment: @DanielGabriel Please update your question and show your `GetAllBinAssemblies` implementation.

Comment: I figured this out. Please see my updated question for a working implementation of `GetAllBinAssemblies`. Thank you. BTW, you were spot on with "Simple Injector is typically not wrong" :)

Comment: @DanielGabriel: Great to hear. Since this is a problem that pops up regularly, while the reason is quite hard to fix, I'm currently trying to improve Simple Injector's error messages to communicate this more clearly. Expected to be added in v3.3.

Comment: @DanielGabriel: I just pushed v3.3.0-beta1 to NuGet. You might want to try it out to see what Simple Injector reports in your case (before the fix of course). If you have any comments on this, you can post them [here](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/325).